# Toolkit Reflective access warning to StartUpWMClassName

Tags: java, linux, reflection, warnings

I am creating an IDE (its opensource, [have a look](https://omegaui.github.io/omegaide)) ,

[image: Main Window]

so in order to change the `StartUpWMClassName` on Linux,

I have used this code:

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
java.lang.reflect.Field field = toolkit.getClass().getDeclaredField("awtAppClassName");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(toolkit, "Omega IDE");
```

And this generates this Warning during runtime:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by ide.Screen (file:/usr/bin/Omega%20IDE.jar) to field sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.awtAppClassName
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of ide.Screen
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Is there another way to do the same without having any warning and also without using `System.setProperty("--illegal-access", "permit")`)?

Comment: Without `System.setProperty("--illegal-access", "permit")` is easy. Since this statement has no effect, you can simply remove it.

Comment: Yes you are right this statement has no effect. Even if I remove it there, there is no effect on program I.e the warnings pop even if it is there.

Comment: @Holger I found that line somewhere on stackoverflow. Do you know answer of my question??

Comment: There is a command line option `--illegal-access=permit` that has nothing to do with system properties. And since it is the default in current Java versions, you don’t need to specify it. When you look closely at the warning text, you’ll notice that it mentions `--illegal-access=warn`, to enable even more warnings. There’s also `--illegal-access=deny`, which is intended to become the default in the future, which is the biggest problem of such reflective accesses (besides the fact that not every JRE implementation has that `awtAppClassName` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the bug report [JDK-6528430](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6528430) which is still open. In other words, there still is no official API to control this feature.

The closest I could find is mentioned in AWT’s [`Taskbar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Taskbar.html):

> Linux support is currently limited to Unity. However to make these features work on Unity, the app should be run from a .desktop file with specified `java.desktop.appName` system property set to this .desktop file name: `Exec=java -Djava.desktop.appName=MyApp.desktop -jar /path/to/myapp.jar`

This system property `java.desktop.appName` only affects features under control of the `Taskbar` implementation, not the entire AWT `Toolkit`.

So, if this is not sufficient, you have to live with the disadvantages of the reflective access. But you have to be aware that this can only be a temporary solution, as future versions will be even more restrictive regarding reflective access, further, the field is not guaranteed to exist at all.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64644482/2711488) contains a work-around, to get rid of the warning. You only have to adapt it to your class and target package.

```java
Module mod = ide.Screen.class.getClassLoader().getUnnamedModule();
if(mod == ide.Screen.class.getModule()) {
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getClass().getModule().addOpens("sun.awt.X11", mod);
}
```

The limitations named in that answer apply to your case as well. This trick only works for the unnamed module, in other words, code loaded via class path. Real modules need a configuration specified at startup time, to open the package for reflective access. As said above, future Java versions may be more restrictive and close this door. Let’s hope that the linked bug gets resolved before that happens, so a switch to an official API is possible then.

Comment: Thanks Holger, you made my day. I think that I should either apply this temporary fix or rename the package `ide` to `Omega` and Screen.java to IDE.java against java convection. If I rename it displays the name as `Omega-IDE` in the activities menu but with that hypen also.

Comment: Yes, this magic happens in [the toolkit’s constructor](https://java-browser.yawk.at/java/15/java.desktop/sun/awt/X11/XToolkit.java#411). It uses the topmost class it can find on the stack and converts its qualified name to a hyphen separated name. You could use a thin wrapper as startup class that only serves the purpose of controlling this name and delegates to the the actual main class immediately. However, even that behavior is not officially documented…

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just going to do the refraction, luckily I checked stackoverflow before.

Comment: I will now create Omega.IDE.java to initialise Screen.java